# How do I get MVC4 Url.Action method to include a hash before the controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently I have this

```
Url.Action("action", "controller", new { area = "", otherParam=""});
```

Which returns `<host>/controller/action?params` as it should.

I want it to return with a hash after the host like this: `<host>/#/controller/action?params`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension to Url Helper:

```
    public static string ActionWithPrefix(this UrlHelper url, string action, string controller, object routeValues)
    {
          return Regex.Replace(url.Action(action, controller, routeValues), @"(/[^/]*/)", @"$1#/");
    }
```

that will return `<AppVirDir>/#/controller/action?params`

Comment: That would have worked if my site was not hosted like this https://site/subpath/ That puts the hash before the subpath so won't work.

Comment: you can write you own Action extension, call the regular Action method and prepend what you need.

Comment: I am starting to think in that direction. Prepending won't work though as Url.Action returns the full url.

Comment: updated to use regex, as possibilty of same name controller as virdir

Comment: glad to help out, make sure to use the latest version of my answer